# Hive - Fixed length list error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am having an issue where when I fetch a list from hive and when I try to add from the list it shows me a fixed list length error. Can somebody help me with it?

```
List<String> test;

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
 test = box.get('test', defaultValue: <String>[]);
}
```

Edit: Turns out this is an active issue opened recently with all the details - https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/602
I guess its a dependency problem as of now.

Comment: You didn't show any code where you try to add to the `List`.  What is the exact error message?  What line does it refer to?  What is the stack trace from the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an older version error in hive, this has been fixed on pub.dev